# Why can't the relativistic version of the position operator in QM/QFT be interpreted as a probability amplitude?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, quantum-electrodynamics

Specifically, I've been trying to understand why it is that the standard position operator in QM is defined as a non-relativistic limit, meaning massless particles can't be localized the same way massive ones can, since they have no non-relativistic limit.  I asked a similar question last week about what goes wrong in the math if we try to localize photons and I did get [a decent answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/762354/268553) saying that, unlike the non-relativistic version, the relativistic version of the position operator can't be interpreted as a probability amplitude.  But I don't understand *why* this is the case. *Why* does having an extra energy term in the denominator mean the expression can't be a probability amplitude? Does that somehow prevent it from being normalized?

Edit: Note that here I'm specifically asking why the relativistic position operator can't be interpreted as a probability amplitude, whereas [this other question I asked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/762622/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-the-position-operator-in-non-relativistic), which some commenters have suggested it's a duplicate of, is asking about what the actual definition of the relativistic position operator is and how it differs from the NR version.  That's a much more general question, which didn't elicit many good answers.  This question is much more specific and focused.  I did get one decent answer to the other question, and so editing that question drastically enough to focus it just on this specific issue would make the already posted answer irrelevant, which wouldn't be fair to that answerer.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of your earlier question at https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/762622/50583 and answered by Valter Moretti's answer there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is the difference between the position operator in non-relativistic QM and the Newton-Wigner operators in QFT?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/762622/)

Comment: @acuriousmind, because that other question I asked was about the specific *definition* of the relativistic position operator.  This question is asking why a specific *property* doesn't apply to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is very simple, but it can be surprisingly hard to find a clear discussion, because standard quantum field theory books choose to avoid discussing position operators at all, for reasons that will be clear below. Mathematical physicists do still discuss it today, but they like to use lots of jargon, which obscures the simplest and most physically important cases. I will give a short answer using notation familiar from undergraduate quantum mechanics.

### The setup

Let $|\mathbf{p} \rangle$ be unit-normalized momentum eigenstates for a relativistic particle. In standard relativistic quantum field theory textbooks, one begins with field operators
$$\hat{\psi}(\mathbf{x}) = \int_{\mathbf{p}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 E_p}} \, (a_{\mathbf{p}} e^{i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}} + b_{\mathbf{p}}^\dagger e^{-i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}})$$
and defines relativistically normalized states by their action,
$$|\mathbf{x} \rangle_{\text{rel}} = \hat{\psi}^\dagger (\mathbf{x}) |0 \rangle = \int_{\mathbf{p}} \frac{e^{- i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}}}{\sqrt{2 E_p}} \, |\mathbf{p} \rangle.$$
Alternatively, one may define the so-called Newton-Wigner states, which match the definition in nonrelativistic quantum mechanics,
$$|\mathbf{x} \rangle_{\text{nw}} = \int_{\mathbf{p}} e^{- i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}}\, |\mathbf{p} \rangle.$$
Using each set of states, one can define a position operator,
$$\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{\text{rel}} |\mathbf{x} \rangle_{\text{rel}} = \mathbf{x} |\mathbf{x} \rangle_{\text{rel}}, \quad \hat{\mathbf{x}}_{\text{nw}} |\mathbf{x} \rangle_{\text{nw}} = \mathbf{x} |\mathbf{x} \rangle_{\text{nw}}$$
as well as position-space wavefunctions
$$\psi(\mathbf{x})_{\text{rel}} = {}_{\text{rel}}\langle \mathbf{x} | \psi \rangle, \quad \psi(\mathbf{x})_{\text{nw}} = {}_{\text{nw}} \langle \mathbf{x} | \psi \rangle. $$
So it's easy to define two separate quantities, each of which one might naively call "the amplitude for a particle to be at position $\mathbf{x}$".

### The problems

So what's the problem? Why don't these simple expressions show up in introductory textbooks?

- The relativistically normalized position states are not orthogonal, as
  $${}_{\text{rel}} \langle \mathbf{y} | \mathbf{x} \rangle_{\text{rel}} = \int_{\mathbf{p}} \frac{e^{i \mathbf{p} \cdot (\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{x})}}{2 E_p} \sim e^{-m |\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}|}$$
  for $|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}| \gg 1/m$. So you can't say a particle is definitely localized at $\mathbf{x}$ if it's in the state $|\mathbf{x} \rangle_{\text{rel}}$, because such a particle also has some amplitude to be in the state $|\mathbf{y}\rangle_{\text{rel}}$.
- The Newton-Wigner position states don't have this problem,
  $${}_{\text{nw}} \langle \mathbf{y} | \mathbf{x} \rangle_{\text{nw}} = \delta(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}).$$
  But they are not Lorentz covariant: if you boost a particle that's in a Newton-Wigner position state, then it won't remain in such a state. That also seems to contradict what it means to be perfectly localized.
- The worst issue is that *both* types of position-space wavefunction obey the equation of motion
  $$i \dot{\psi}(\mathbf{x}) = \sqrt{- \nabla^2 + m^2} \, \psi(\mathbf{x})$$
  which is simply the Klein-Gordan equation restricted to positive frequencies. This is fatal, as solutions of this equation generically spread superluminally!  For instance, if the support of $\psi(\mathbf{x})$ is restricted to a finite region, then after an infinitesimal time, it will spread out infinitely far. So you cannot say that $|\psi(\mathbf{x})|^2$ is the probability density to detect a particle at $\mathbf{x}$. If that were actually true, then one could signal faster than light, violating causality.

Because of this final issue, it is very difficult to see how relativistic quantum mechanics can be causal, at the level of particle operators. Causality is only straightforward if you write all interactions in terms of local products of Lorentz covariant fields -- which is the approach taken by all modern textbooks. The tradeoff is that this language doesn't let you speak of the precise positions of particles.

Comment: "The tradeoff is that this language doesn't let you speak of the precise positions of particles." Hmm.  Does that tradeoff between locality and causality have anything to do with how Belle's theorem rules out local realism as a valid interpretation of QM?

Comment: @MikaylaEckelCifrese No, this is a distinct issue. Bell’s theorem doesn’t care about relativity (it’s a general statement about any quantum theory, relativistic or not) while this issue is intimately tied to relativity.

Comment: @MikaylaEckelCifrese They’re somewhat related in spirit though: if you believe in locality, then Bell inequality violations force you to give up a picture of classical particles in favor of quantum particles. And this issue forces you to give up a picture of quantum particles in favor of quantum fields.